# HTML Audio - The volume provided (-0.1) is outside the range - Math max not working

Tags: javascript

I have created a volume down button I am trying to prevent the volume from going under 0.0. For some reason, the Math.max is not working correctly. Not sure what I am doing wrong by checking the current value/time.

How can I add a logic that If the volume is equal to 0.0 to return and do nothing?

See -> Arrow down keyCode 40.

```
(() => {
    const audio = document.querySelector('audio');
    const playButton = document.getElementById('play');
    const progress = document.querySelector('.player__progress');
    const progressBar = document.querySelector('.player__progress__inner');
    const next = document.getElementById('next');
    const prev = document.getElementById('previous');
    const title = document.querySelector('.title');
    const status = document.querySelector('.status');
    const poster = document.querySelector('.player__image');

    if (!audio) {
        return;
    }

    // On play button click.
    const onPlayStart = () => {
        audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
    };

    // On audio playing.
    const onPlaying = () => {
        playButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-pause"></i>`;

        // Change title if is currently playing.
        // status.innerText = `status: Wordt afgespeeld.`;
    };

    // On audio paused.
    const onPaused = () => {
        playButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-play"></i>`;

        // Change title if is currently paused.
        // status.innerText = `status: Is gepauzeerd.`;
    };

    // Update progress bar
    const onTimeUpdate = () => {
        const percent = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100;
        progressBar.style.width = `${percent}%`;
    };

    // Update progress on click
    const onProgressUpdate = (e) => {
        audio.currentTime = (e.offsetX / progress.clientWidth) * audio.duration;
    };

    const onKeyPress = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Spacebar
        if (e.keyCode === 32) {
            audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
        }

        // Right arrow
        if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            // Forward by 10 sec.
            audio.currentTime += 10;
        }

        // Left arrow
        if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            // Backward by 10 sec
            audio.currentTime -= 10;
        }

        // Up arrow
        if (e.keyCode === 38) {
            // Volume up
            if (audio.volume < 1.0) {
                audio.volume += 0.1;
            }
        }

        // Arrow down
        if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            // Volume down

            if (audio.volume === Math.max(0, audio.volume - 0.01)) {
                return;
            }

            if (audio.volume >= 0.0) {
                audio.volume -= 0.1;
            }
        }
    };

    audio.addEventListener('play', onPlaying);
    audio.addEventListener('pause', onPaused);
    audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', onTimeUpdate);

    document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyPress);
    progress.addEventListener('click', onProgressUpdate);
    playButton.addEventListener('click', onPlayStart);
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use these functions below. They check if a value has reached a certain threshold and make a calculation if they don't, otherwise it just returns the value.

This means, in case for the increment, that it keeps adding until `1` is reached and then just returns `1` without counting upwards, effectively stopping the increment.

The calculation is because of floating point numbers not being precise. This makes sure that every value is exactly a one decimal point number (`0.1`, `0.2`, `0.3`, ect).

```
const incrementVolume = value => 
    value < 1 ? (value * 10 + 1) / 10 : value;

const decrementVolume = value => 
    value > 0 ? (value * 10 - 1) / 10 : value;
```

Then implement these functions in your if statements where they reassign the `volume` property.

```
// Arrow up
if (e.keyCode === 38) {
  // Volume up
  audio.volume = incrementVolume(audio.volume);
}

// Arrow down
if (e.keyCode === 40) {
  // Volume down
  audio.volume = decrementVolume(audio.volume);
}
```